# How do I calculate the days per month given a start date and a duration?

Tags: php, datetime, codeigniter

Trying to figure out a small problem. I have a start date and a duration (in weeks) and need to calculate the number of work days per month over the duration.

For example: 
Start Date: 2011-02-07
Duration: 10 weeks

I'd like to get back the following:

Feb: 16 days
March: 23 days
April: 11 days

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Work days from Monday to Friday?

Comment: Maybe this could help you figuring it out: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261179/working-days-mon-fri-in-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261179/working-days-mon-fri-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pre 5.3 solution:

```
$start = $current = strtotime('2011-02-07');
$end = strtotime('+10 weeks', $start);
$months = array();
while($current < $end) {
    $month = date('M', $current);
    if (!isset($months[$month])) {
        $months[$month] = 0;
    }
    $months[$month]++;
    $current = strtotime('+1 weekday', $current);
}
print_r($months);
```

Output ([codepad](http://codepad.org/RaOWxbd1)):

```
Array
(
    [Feb] => 16
    [Mar] => 23
    [Apr] => 11
)
```

Comment: @gordon what if the date and the duration are variables? Duration is an int like 10 and date is the same. Sorry should have been more clear.

Comment: @Brian not an issue: `strtotime($date); strtotime("+$w weeks")`

Comment: @gordon what is I want to add a value to the finial number of days per month? I'm not sure where to add that in as it's counting.

Comment: @Brian the approach above does not know when it shifts from one month to the other, so you would have to add a $previousMonth variable and compare that against the $month variable and when they are not the same you know that a new month started. As an alternative simply use `array_walk` or `array_map` on the result array.

Answer (score 3):

```
$start=date_create('2011-02-07');
$interval=new DateInterval('P10W');
$end=date_add(clone $start,$interval);//use clone otherwise $start gets changed

$period=new DatePeriod($start, new DateInterval('P1D'), $end);

foreach($period as $day){
  if($day->format('N')<6) $workdays[$day->format('F')]++; //N is 1-7 where Monday=1
}

var_dump($workdays);
```

Comment: That's what I get as well. Also how would I set up a variable for DateInterval?

Comment: Also I don't think that I have DateInterval available as it's only in 5.3 any way to accomplish this without that?

Comment: You need PHP greater or equal to version 5.3.0

Comment: @Gordon: fixed the syntax error- forgot to close a parenthesis.  Also, added `clone` to the `date_add` line because of the weird way that function works.  However, you do have to use PHP5.3 or better for this method.  For prior versions you can do the math with `date()` but you will likely run into issues with leap years and other edge cases that the new DateTime/DateInterval/DatePeriod objects handle for you.

Comment: @Gordon: the notices are about undefined indices and variable.  If you want to avoid them, you can initialize `$workdays=array('January'=>0,...)` before the loop.

Comment: @Gordon: no worries.  Were this production code, it would be complete.