# Add Days from Input Type Date and Input Type Duration PHP Excluding Weekends + MYSQL National Holiday

Tags: php

I need to add days (input type number + input type date) but the result must be an array so I can INSERT one after another into the Database.

> Here's the code (After HTML Form submitted):
>
> ```html
> <?php
>
> $start_date = '2017-12-22';
> $duration = '3';
> $d = new DateTime($start_date);
> $t = $d->getTimestamp();
>
> // loop for X days
> for($i=0; $i <= $duration; $i++){
>
>     // add 1 day to timestamp-
>     $addDay = 86400;
>
>     // get what day it is next day
>     $nextDay = date('w', ($t + $addDay));
>     
>     // if it's Saturday or Sunday get $i-1
>     if($nextDay === 6 || $nextDay === 7) {
>         $i --;
>     }
>
>     // modify timestamp, add 1 day
>     $t = $t + $addDay;
>     
>     $d->setTimestamp($t);
>     $day_off = $d->format( 'Y-m-d' ). "<br />";
>     
>     echo $day_off;
>     
>     $query = "INSERT SQL";
>     
> }
>
> ?>
> ```
>
> From **echo $day_off** result I get:
>
> ```html
> 2017-12-23
> 2017-12-24
> 2017-12-25
> 2017-12-26
> ```
>
> Instead of 23, 24, 25, 26. I need to get the result below:
>
> 2017-12-22
>       2017-12-25
>       2017-12-26
>       2017-12-27

> 22 is the input date, start from 25 because 23 and 24 are Sat and Sun and weekends need to be excluded.
>
> How can I achieve this result? I've been searching on the net but unfortunately, I couldn't find what I needed.

**@C. Geek** answer made it to works, but I have a more complex question here, since my account are not eligible to ask more question so I'll ask here.

So here's what I've tried so far (with **@C. Geek** answer) :

```html
<?php

// loop for X days
for($i=0; $i < $duration; $i++){
    
    
    $d = strtotime("$start_date +$i weekdays");
    $t = strftime("%Y-%m-%d",$d);
    
    $day_off[] = $t;
    
    foreach($day_off as $dayoff) {
        
        $data_holiday = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `holiday_master_data` WHERE `date` = '$dayoff' "));
        
    }
    
    $holiday[] = $data_holiday['date'];
    $date = array_diff($day_off, $holiday);
    $dayoff_ = $holiday;
    
?>
```

Start date : 2017-12-29
Duration : 5 days

From **print_r($day_off);** I'm getting this result :

> Array ( [0] => 2017-12-29 ) Array ( [0] => 2017-12-29 [1] => 2018-01-01 ) Array ( [0] => 2017-12-29 [1] => 2018-01-01 [2] => 2018-01-02 )

And from **print_r($holiday);** I'm getting this result :

> Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => [1] => 2018-01-01 ) Array ( [0] => [1] => 2018-01-01 [2] => ) Array ( [0] => [1] => 2018-01-01 [2] => [3] => ) Array ( [0] => [1] => 2018-01-01 [2] => [3] => [4] => )

The national date fetched from database is 2018-01-01 with 5 looping result, the final date result I need to make are 29 Dec, 02 Jan 03 Jan and 04 Jan, 05 Jan.

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4261223/6288442

> If you are limiting to weekdays use the string weekdays.
>
> ```
> echo date ( 'Y-m-j' , strtotime ( '3 weekdays' ) );
> ```
>
> This should jump you ahead by 3 weekdays, so if it is Thursday it will
>   add the additional weekend time.
>
> Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

As for formatting:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

```
 string strftime ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )
```

If you need more help with writing the code than these, please do tell in a comment

Here is my full answer:

```
$start_date = '2017-12-22';
$duration = 3;
$arr=null;
for($i=0; $i <= $duration; $i++){
    $d = strtotime("$start_date +$i weekdays");
    $t = strftime("%Y-%m-%d",$d);
    $arr[]=$t;
}
```

Get the holidays before the looping, then in the loop, check if date is in_array before adding it to $arr.
e.g.

```
$start_date = '2017-12-22';  
$data_holiday = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `holiday_master_data` WHERE YEAR(`date`) BETWEEN YEAR('$start_date') AND YEAR('$start_date')+1 "));
$holidays = 
$duration = 3;
$arr=null;
for($i=0; $i <= $duration; $i++){
    $d = strtotime("$start_date +$i weekdays");
    $t = strftime("%Y-%m-%d",$d);
    if(!in_array($t,$data_holiday))
        $arr[]=$t;
}
```

Comment: I definitely need a hand in writing the code. Would you please write the code please. Thanks.

Comment: Hey man, can I ask you more question? I don't know why but stackoverflow give me this error when I try to ask a new question. It's say, **You have reached your question limit**

Comment: Hello, if the above worked for you, please upvote my answer and choose it as an answer :D

Comment: I'll upvote it for sure, now I'm editing this question because the question limit blocked me to ask another question. I'm not sure how many questions I've made.

Comment: hmmm, I don't have a problem with that but I do not know what the moderators would think...

Comment: I'm also afraid moderator will do something to my account, currently still editing and probably would make a decision to make an update to this question. Well, by any chance, can I ask you in PM or something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162323/discussion-between-c-geek-and-m-ansyori).

Comment: @MAnsyori Fixed

Comment: It's working when I put $start_date = value_in_db (2018-01-01). But when I enter start date 29 Dec 2017 it's not working, the result still give me 2018-01-01?

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY!! After several hours I fixed everything. Here's the code how I manage to skip (Sun and Monday) and also Skip the Holiday's fetched from the database (based on **@C.Geek** answers + several tweaking):

```html
<?php

include 'conn.php';
$start_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['start_date']);
$duration = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['duration']);

// loop for X days
for($i=0; $i <= $duration; $i++){
    
    $d = strtotime("$start_date +$i weekdays");
    $t = explode(", ", strftime("%Y-%m-%d", $d));
    
    foreach ($t as $date) {
        
        $to_encode = array("date" => $date);
        $date_where = $to_encode['date'];
        
        $data_holiday = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `date` AS '0' FROM `holiday_master_data` WHERE DATE(`date`) BETWEEN DATE('$date_where') AND DATE('$date_where') + 1 GROUP BY `id` "));
        
        $encode_holiday = array("date" => $data_holiday[0]);
        
        break;
        
    }
    
    $holiday = array_unique($encode_holiday);
    $dayoff = array_diff($t, $holiday);
    
    foreach($dayoff as $date) {
        
        $query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO ");
    
        if ($query) {
            echo "<script>alert('Absence Saved'); window.location ='document.php' </script>";
        } else {
            echo "<script>alert('Gagal'); window.location ='document.php' </script>";
        }
    }
    
    
}

?>
```

Hope this helps anyone seeking the same problem I had.

Cheers.